# Is it possible for no points to lie on the "gutters" in a hard-margin SVM?

Tags: svm

I am taught that the hard-margin SVM is defined as the optimization problem:

$\min_{w, b} \frac{1}{2}||w||^2_2, \text{ s.t. } y_i(\langle x_i, w \rangle + b) \ge 1$

Furthermore, the two planes $\langle x, w \rangle + b = \pm 1$ are the "gutters" on the margin where the closest points will lie. I am wondering if it is possible for no points at all to lie on these gutters; that is, $\forall i, y_i(\langle x_i, w \rangle + b) > 1$. I am guessing this is impossible, and have come up with the following reasoning:

WLOG if the closest positive point is $\langle x_i, w \rangle + b = a$ where $a > 1$, then $\frac{1}{a}(\langle x_i, w \rangle + b) = \langle x_i, \frac{1}{a}w \rangle + \frac{1}{a}b = 1$, and $||\frac{1}{a}w||^2_2 < ||w||^2_2$. Dividing both $w$ and $b$ by $a$ yields the same separating hyperplane, which means $\min_{w, b} \frac{1}{2}||w||^2_2$ is violated.

This is very handwavy and I am not quite sure myself. If anyone could provide better intuition and a more rigorous explanation, I'd appreciate it!